# GraphQL Integrated not functioning correctly on CD server, working on CM

Tags: sxa, jss, graphql

I'm having a problem on our site setup with `Sitecore 10.2`, `Sitecore Headless Services 19.0` and `SXA`. `GraphQL` integrated isn't returning data correctly on our `CD` site, it is only working properly on the content management (`CM`) server - though it is also not returning data on the `layout service` API (`/sitecore/api/layout/render`).

The problem is that no data is being returned to the page/in the API. On the pages, when accessed from the CM (e.g. page edit mode, but also with `sc_mode`), the data from `GraphQL` queries comes through as expected. Using the `GraphQL` playground (`/sitecore/api/graph/edge/ui`), the `GraphQL` statements function as expected (the `GraphQL` playground is only accessible on the CM server). `GraphQL` connected is working properly across all modes/servers.

I've tried different pages, different renderings, and modifying the `NextJS` components to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your issue as you mention it is working on the CM - but we had [an issue with integrated GraphQL](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2022/02/my-first-jss-story.html) on an 10.2 headless setup including SXA.

The issue was solved by this kb: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000658

Might seem completely unrelated but it solved the problem for us. After deleting the config file `modules/sxa/z.layout.service/layout.service.config` the integrated mode worked.

If this doesn't fix, you should compare your config files between CM and CD to check for differences - and also check if there are no GraphQL related parts that get changed by the environment patching.

Comment: Deleting that config using the dockerfile line in your article worked! Thanks!